# vue draggable table with fixed column

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table of 2 columns, one column has a static list of values and the next column I need to be draggable so that I can move the cells in the second column up and down etc without affecting the first column.

Use case is a list of time slots and second column is a persons name, I will add name to the cell but then might want to drag that to a different time slot.

I have got table showing the times but not able to get the second bit working- the most important bit.

Any idea how to do this, maybe a table isn't the way to go?
Thanks

Comment: Could you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: yes what i have so far https://codesandbox.io/s/wwyymm5695

Comment: with the code i have in the sandbox i feel i am quite close, im thinking maybe i need to do something with the events that are emitted

Comment: @SamCodeBad have you been able to look at the code to see if you can help.thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wqkw71jj45) is an updated version where you can drag into the timeslots. I put both views into one to make it a bit easier to read.

I changed the timeslot structure to be:

```
  times: [
    { id: 1, time: "09:00", people: [] },
    { id: 2, time: "09:30", people: [] },
    { id: 3, time: "10:00", people: [] }
  ],
```

So now you are just dragging the people into the times.people arrays.

Comment: ok thank  you, that looks good, i have added another draggable around the span so that i can reorder within the timeslot and move individual out of timeslot. Will have to look into the draggable events to enable/restrict certain funtionality.